# Jmeter returing "Loading AppComponent content here " as response data

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to do load testing for a webpage(angular 2), the response data i am getting in tool is "Loading Appcomponent content here ..".

I need the full html to be displayed in response data. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter project main page](http://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter **is not a browser**, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript** found in HTML pages. **Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does** (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So if your application content is being loaded via JavaScript calls (the technology is known as [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)) JMeter won't trigger JavaScript-driven requests as it is not capable of parsing them.

However you can capture the relevant requests using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and see the responses, most probably they will come as [XML](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp) or [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) so you won't see the "real" page, but you will get the data and will be able to measure the requests timings.

Also AJAX requests need to be handled a little bit differently comparing to "normal" sequential HTTP requests as in the majority of cases browsers execute them in parallel, see [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) article for more details.